# Generating components with nested maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The goal is to produce this ...

```js
<option value={1}>$</option>
<option value={2}>$$</option>
<option value={3}>$$$</option>
<option value={4}>$$$$</option>
```

using a map.

I tried this ...

```js
let money = ['$', '$$', '$$$', '$$$$' ]
money.map(function(val, i) { <option value={i + 1}> val.map(function(char, j) {return char} </option> )});
```

But I think im missing some very fundamental knowledge to make this work properly.

Comment: your map function needs to return

Comment: Also `i` in your case in index which will begin as `0`, I assume you want it to begin with `1`

Comment: If I add a return to the inner map its a ```Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression``` and If i add it to both its a parsing error. @Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Array#map` doesn't return anything and arrays start counting from 0. I'm also assuming your environment supports JSX. With that said, try this:

```js
const money = ['$', '$$', '$$$', '$$$$' ]
money.map((val, i) => <option value={i + 1}>{val}</option>);
```

Comment: I am using JSX, is it a one to one translation between template literals and {}

Comment: @WhiffWham Template literals work similarly everywhere. I've updated my answer to use JSX.

Answer (score -2):

`money.map((val, i) =>  <option value={i+1} key={i}>{val}</option>)`